# Has anyone experienced Laravel Artisan commands returning the opening <?php tag in responses

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7, artisan-migrate

I have been putting together a web application with the latest version of the Laravel framework (5.7 as of current time) and i have noticed a rather frustrating bug with the Artisan functionality.

As an example when i run php artisan migrate i get the below example response:

```
<?php nothing to migrate
```

The issue here is not the fact that there are no migrations because i have those working no problem however notice the `<?php` tag in the response, this happens no matter what Artisan command i run and it is rather annoying when running commands from a route because it breaks my json responses because of the php tag so my responses look like this:

```
<?php{"status": 200, "message": "test message"}
```

It seems to be the php tag within the artisan file however the tag needs to be there as the file is parsed as php. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Installed any packages that could cause this? How do you call those artisan commands? Do all artisan commands (including `php artisan`) have that same `<?php` added? Are there maybe any `<?php <?php` "typos" somewhere in your code?

Comment: This was the same even on a fresh install of Laravel with no custom packages, the artisan commands are called through the command prompt in the root of the application

Comment: scrap that above comment, fresh install worked. Clearly i have broken something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mostly check you configuration files in the folde `config/`.

if there is any text, example `<?php <?php` before the `return [...]` it will be present in every console command.

for fpm, laravel clears the output before sending the responses.

I doubt that the error is in the installad packages, cause it will be quickly reported, unless you are using a very uncommon package.

Comment: Interesting, i will have a look. I am using PHP-FPM andit does not seem to clear the tags from the output. I think you are right about the packages because this problem shows even on a fresh install with no custom packages on top of the default requirements of Laravel

Comment: I have just checked the config files and they only contain one opening tag as would normally be the case

Comment: @ChrisHarker have you checked the end of the files, outside the array returned?
you should also check `public/index.php` and every file included directly from there.

Comment: Many thanks N69S, although it was not the config files it was indeed a file in the system that broke it. It was the console.php route file that was empty apart from the php tag.